# java applet not working in html

Tags: java, html, swing, applet

I have a very simple problem.  My "Hello World" applet is not transferring into html for some reason.

I am providing the code class and code base to upload the file, but for some reason, the html states that there is an error and the error looks like a bunch of commands from an operating system terminal.

I am using Mac OS and the coding for the Java and HTML are the following:

```
import java.awt.*;

public class Hello extends javax.swing.JApplet {
    String greeting;

    public void init() {
        FlowLayout flo = new FlowLayout();
        setLayout(flo);
        greeting = "Hello!";
    }

    public void paint(Graphics screen) {
        Graphics2D screen2D = (Graphics2D) screen;
        screen2D.drawString(greeting, 25, 50);
    }
}
```

I have the HTML set up properly with the tags, head, title, and body.  The applet is in the body and is coded as the following:

```
applet width="400" height="200" codebase="..\\..\\build\\classes" code="Hello.class"
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Where are the `<` and `>` in the HTML?

Comment: 1) *"the html states that there is an error and the error looks like a bunch of commands from an operating system terminal."*  That does not help us to help you.  Copy/paste the messages.  2) That HTML is invalid, check it using a [validation service](http://validator.w3.org/).  I doubt the validation service will pick it up, but all paths in applets should have / instead of \. 3) Not breaking the applet, but change code attribute to `code="Hello"` 4) I don't recommend coding applets at your stage of experience, and not to mix together custom painting and components - both advanced topics.

Comment: I'm also concerned about your codebase.  What is the error?

Comment: And where's the `super.paint(screen)`?  Don't going to fix your immediate issue, but will make your life much easier in the long run

Comment: See [*Initial Threads*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html), also required for applets.

Comment: Apologies, I could have set this up a little better.  This is what I get, when I run the applet on a browser:  Java Plug-in 10.9.2.05
Using JRE version 1.7.0_09-b05 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
c:   clear console window
f:   finalize objects on finalization queue
g:   garbage collect
h:   display this help message
l:   dump classloader list
m:   print memory usage
o:   trigger logging
q:   hide console
r:   reload policy configuration
s:   dump system and deployment properties
t:   dump thread list
v:   dump thread stack
x:   clear classloader cache
0-5: set trace level to <n>

Answer (score 1):

Create an html file in the directory where Hello.class is, containing this:

```
<applet width="400" height="200" codebase="." code="Hello.class">
```

Open it with your browser, and if your Java plugin is configured correctly you should see the applet. It works for me:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response, Diego, but still the same problems.  Do I have to compile the Java code in order to get it to work?  My browser(s) have the java plugins enabled, but they simply aren't running this simple line of code.  Must code be compiled, exported, or have something else done to it before it can be broadcast on a web page?

Comment: Of course you have to compile your Java code. That's how you generate the .class file that the html file references.

Comment: Thanks for your assistance, I am able to get applets working now.  Appreciate your and everyone else's help.